# Codeigniter creating css_url() and reaching assets in view

Tags: codeigniter, directory

I added new function which is called `css_url`. I set in constructor of controller, It works.
Besides, I want to reach in assets in view. In view directory I put themes, and each themes has own assets. How can I reach assets in view directory?

```
-view
--theme1
---assets
----css
----js
----images
-----f1.jpg
```

->

```
public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    // Temel veriler veri tabanından çekilecek;
    $this -> theme = "theme1";

    $this->config->set_item('css_url', $this->theme.'/assets/');
}

css_url("images/f1.jpg");
```

Comment: Post the `css_url()` function as well; How does it work?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$this->config->set_item('css_url', APPLICATION_PATH . '/DIFFERENT_DEPENDING_ON_VERSION_OF_CI/'.$this -> theme.'/assets/');
```

The differences in codeingiter versions are because of where the application path is. It could be /system/application, it could be just /application/

Comment: APPPATH exists instead of APPLICATION_PATH but it gives forbbiden error.

Comment: Possibly make sure their ownership is whatever user Apache uses to run. Sometimes www_data, sometimes _www, sometimes something else. depends on your OS.